# Codeigniter - join value from two tables with same column name

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have two table which is `riders` and `teams`, and i like to show my data in my table, but the problem is both of those table have the same column name which is `name`, here for example :

**Table riders**

[image]

**Table Teams**

[image]

and here is the `view` in my table :

[image]

so what im trying to do is to join both table and make alias for the `id_team`, so that i can get the team `name` instead of their `id_team`, but since they had the same column name, i dont know how to do it, here is my model :

```
public function show()
{
    $this->db->select('team.id_team, team.name, rider.*', false);
    $this->db->from('teams as team');
    $this->db->join('riders as rider', 'team.id_team = rider.id_team');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

here is my controller :

```
public function index()
{
  $data['riders_data'] = $this->riders->show();

  $this->load->view('back-end/template/header');
  $this->load->view('back-end/master-rider', $data);
  $this->load->view('back-end/template/footer');
}
```

and here is my table in my view :

```
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach($riders_data as $rider) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><img src="<?=base_url('/assets/riders/'.$rider->image); ?>" alt="" width="50px"></td>
        <td><?php echo $rider->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rider->number; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rider->country; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rider->id_team; ?></td> //team name
    </tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

any help is really appreciated, thank you!.

Comment: Give one of the `name` columns an alias `select('team.id_team, team.name as team_name, rider.*'` Then that column shoudl be referenced in the PHP using `team_name`

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: thank you so much for the reference!, yup i really need to fix my code.